# Angular 8 issue with subscribing to variable in service

Tags: angular, rxjs, httprequest, listener, rxjs6

I'm learning Angular and trying to listen to a variable holding the http request value. Here's the service

```
export class UsersService {
 message = new Subject<string>();
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 addUser(userData: {username, email, password, school}) {
   this.http.post<any>('http://127.0.0.1/apiapp/insert.php', userData).subscribe( (r) => {
     this.message = r.message;
   });
}
```

When I log the message I get `success`
Now I want to call this function and listen to that variable from the component

```
result = '';
private resultSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resultSubscription = this.userS.message.subscribe( (r) => {
      this.result = r;
    });
 }

  addPost(userData: {username: string, email: string, password: string, school: string}) {
    this.userS.addUser(userData);
    console.log(this.result);    
 }
```

I get a blank data (nothing logged just a blank row in the console). Why is that and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 issues here.

- You aren't sending the value correctly via the subject
- you having some async issues with the location of your `console.log(this.result)`
- You'll want to call `.asObservable` on your subject to get subject as observable

  ```
  export class UsersService {
      message = new Subject<string>();
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      addUser(userData: {username, email, password, school}) {
          this.http.post<any>('http://127.0.0.1/apiapp/insert.php', userData).subscribe( (r) => {
          // .next is how you send data via a subject
          this.message.next(r.message);
      });
  }




  result = '';
  private resultSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
      // Get subject as observable
      this.resultSubscription = this.userS.message.asObservable().subscribe( (r) => {
          this.result = r;
          // by logging here we can ensure that the result will be populated
          console.log(this.result);  
      });
  }

  addPost(userData: {username: string, email: string, password: string, school: string}) {
      this.userS.addUser(userData);
  }

  // It is important to unsubscribe for your observable when the component is destroyed
  ngOnDestroy(): void { this.resultSubscription.unsubscribe(); }
  ```

Comment: ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.resultSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
this is important to prevent memory leak in this situation right?

Comment: @PHPUser you are correct, completely forgot about that. my apologies